# 1つのフォルダにまとめたファイル群を何回層もあるサブディレクトリ群にコピー

Tags: windows, batch-file

タイトルの通りですが、まず1つのフォルダに複数のファイルが存在します。
そのフォルダ内全てのファイルを複数のサブディレクトリの全ての中にコピーしたいです。

```
フォルダA ┳ コピーしたい.txt
       　┣ コピーしたい.csv
       　┗ コピーしたい.csv

フォルダB　　┳　フォルダc ┳ フォルダi
(コピー先)   ┃           ┗ フォルダj
            ┣ フォルダd
...etc
```

環境はWindows10 64bit版です。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: コピー元のファイルをコピー先のどのディレクトリにコピーするのか、対応条件を記載された方が回答を得られやすくなるかと思います。

Comment: 「フォルダAの中身」を、フォルダB以下のサブフォルダすべてに「繰り返しコピー」させたい、ということでしょうか。

Comment: ログインし直しましたが>1です　@cubik 様　はい。その通りでございます。フォルダB以下のサブディレクトリ内全てです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

フォルダAのサブフォルダはコピーせず、フォルダB自体を除いてサブフォルダにコピーする例です。

バッチファイル(バッチファイルではなくコマンドラインの場合は`%%D`を`%D`に書き直してください)

```
SET SRC=C:\test\フォルダA
CD /D C:\test\フォルダB
FOR /D /R %%D IN (*) DO (ROBOCOPY "%SRC%" "%%D")
```

PowerShell

```
ls "C:\test\フォルダB" -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | %{
   robocopy "C:\test\フォルダA" $_.FullName
}
```